# Arithmetic conversion grams to kilograms

Tags: javascript, function, math

I am trying to change grams to kilograms when the value is more than 1000 grams to 1 kg but is not working. If you run the code and increase the value to 2 the first value will be 1400 g instead of 1.4 kg that I want to display.

```js
function multiplyBy() {
  var x = document.getElementById("serves").value;

  var a = 700;
  var b = 2;
  var c = 0.4;
  var d = 20;
  var e = 1;

  var kg = 1000;

  var i1 = x * a;
  var i2 = x * b;
  var i3 = x * c;
  var i4 = x * d;
  var i5 = x * e;

  if (i1 >= kg + " g") {
    document.getElementById("ing1").innerHTML = +(i1 / kg) + " g";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ing1").innerHTML = +i1 + " g";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("ing2").innerHTML = +i2 + " g";
  document.getElementById("ing3").innerHTML = (+i3.toFixed(1)) + " g";
  document.getElementById("ing4").innerHTML = +i4 + " g";
  document.getElementById("ing5").innerHTML = +i5 + " g";
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="100" id="serves" />
<input type="button" onClick="multiplyBy()" Value="Calculate" />
<br><br>
<div id="ing1">700 g</div>
<div id="ing2">200 g</div>
<div id="ing3">0.4 g</div>
<div id="ing4">20 ml</div>
<div id="ing5">1 </div>
```

Comment: That appears to be Java*Script*.

Comment: `Thanks it worked!!!` lo and behold - I would have bet it showed the wrong unit of mass (`g` instead of `kg`)

Answer (score 0):

the condition in if block was evaluating to false, please try this.

```
document.getElementById("ing1").innerHTML = i1 > kg ? (i1 / kg) + 'kg' : i1 + 'g';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i1 >= kg + " g")
```

If you append `" g"` to `kg`, you’re comparing `i1 >= "1000 g"`, which in the case of `x === 2` is `1400 >= "1000 g"`. Since one of the operands is a string, it will be coerced to `NaN`, and *every comparison*, no matter what `i1` is, will return `false`. You want:

```
if (i1 >= kg)
```

And then, append `+ " kg"` to the resulting string instead of `+ " g"`.

---

While the above solves and explains the issue, I will add a different, simpler approach, along with some advice:

- [Don’t use inline `onclick` attributes.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871640/4642212) Instead use standard [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- There’s no point in using the [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) before `i1` etc. when concatenating `" g"`. They’re already numbers, and will become part of a string, anyway.
- Don’t use this many IDs. It’s far simpler to wrap all those `<div>`s in a single `<div>` with one ID instead:

```html
<div id="ing">
  <div>700 g</div>
  <div>200 g</div>
  <div>0.4 g</div>
  <div>20 ml</div>
  <div>1 </div>
</div>
```

- Then, iterate over the `<div>`’s [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children), and use some functional programming instead, especially [`Array` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2) ([Destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are in there, too).

```js
// Get initial amounts and units from <div>s here.
const amounts = Array.from(document.getElementById("ing").children, (child) => {
      let [amount, unit] = child.innerText.split(" ");

      return {
        amount: Number(amount),
        unit: unit || "", // If there is no space in the string (e.g. just "10"), then `unit` should be the empty string (without `|| ""` it will be `undefined`).
        div: child
      };
    }),
    button = document.getElementById("button"), // Add an ID "button" to the “Calculate” button, instead of an `onclick` attribute
    kg = 1000;

function multiplyBy(){
  const serves = Number(document.getElementById("serves").value); // You use this as a number, but .value returns a string. Better convert it immediately, to avoid future errors.

  amounts.forEach(({amount, unit, div}) => {
    const multipliedAmount = amount * serves,
      useKg = unit === "g" && multipliedAmount >= kg; // This condition holds iff the multiplied amount is at least 1000 g.

    div.innerText = `${Number((multipliedAmount / (useKg ? kg : 1)).toFixed(1))} ${useKg ? "kg" : unit}`;
  });
}

button.addEventListener("click", multiplyBy); // Assign the click handler here.

// Alternatively: ditch the button and use a change listener on the `serves` input instead:
// document.getElementById("serves").addEventListener("change", multiplyBy);
```

This will also take care of different units remaining their own units, instead of becoming `g`. See the following snippet for a working example:

```js
// Get initial amounts and units from <div>s here.
const amounts = Array.from(document.getElementById("ing").children, (child) => {
      let [amount, unit] = child.innerText.split(" ");
      
      return {
        amount: Number(amount),
        unit: unit || "", // If there is no space in the string (e.g. just "10"), then `unit` should be the empty string (without `|| ""` it will be `undefined`).
        div: child
      };
    }),
    button = document.getElementById("button"), // Add an ID "button" to the “Calculate” button, instead of an `onclick` attribute
    kg = 1000;

function multiplyBy(){
  const serves = Number(document.getElementById("serves").value); // You use this as a number, but .value returns a string. Better convert it immediately, to avoid future errors.
  
  amounts.forEach(({amount, unit, div}) => {
    const multipliedAmount = amount * serves,
      useKg = unit === "g" && multipliedAmount >= kg; // This condition holds iff the multiplied amount is at least 1000 g.
    
    div.innerText = `${Number((multipliedAmount / (useKg ? kg : 1)).toFixed(1))} ${useKg ? "kg" : unit}`;
  });
}

button.addEventListener("click", multiplyBy); // Assign the click handler here.

// Alternatively: ditch the button and use a change listener on the `serves` input instead:
// document.getElementById("serves").addEventListener("change", multiplyBy);
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="100" id="serves"/>
<input type="button" id="button" Value="Calculate"/>
<br/><br/>
<div id="ing">
  <div>700 g</div>
  <div>200 g</div>
  <div>0.4 g</div>
  <div>20 ml</div>
  <div>1 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (i1 >= kg) {
    document.getElementById("ing1").innerHTML = (i1 / kg) + " kg";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ing1").innerHTML = i1 + " g";
  }
```